# If the tangent at the point $(x_1,y_1)$ to the curve $x^3+y^3=a^3(a\ne 0)$ meets the curve again in $(x_2,y_2)$

Tags: calculus

If the tangent at the point $(x_1,y_1)$ to the curve $x^3+y^3=a^3(a\ne 0)$ meets the curve again in $(x_2,y_2)$ then show that $\frac{x_2}{x_1}+\frac{y_2}{y_1}=-1$.

---

$x^3+y^3=a^3\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x^2}{y^2}$
So the equation of the tangent to the curve at $(x_1,y_1)$ is $y-y_1=\frac{-x_1^2}{y_1^2}(x-x_1)$
Upon simplifying we get
$xx^2_1+yy^2_1=a^3$
This tangent line will again meet the curve in $(x_2,y_2)$.
So $x_2x^2_1+y_2y^2_1=a^3...........(1)$
Also $(x_2,y_2)$ is on the curve $x^3+y^3=a^3$,so $x_2^3+y_2^3=a^3.......(2)$
Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, i tried to prove $\frac{x_2}{x_1}+\frac{y_2}{y_1}=-1$,but i am not able to prove it.
Please help.

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/If-a-tangent-at-point-x1-y1-to-a-curve-x-3+y-3-a-3-meets-the-curve-again-at-point-x2-y2-how-does-one-prove-that-x2-x1-+-y2-y1-1